# How to add text to a dashboard in Databricks

Tags: databricks

I'm trying to add a text box to a dashboard in Databricks.  The guide at https://docs.databricks.com/sql/user/dashboards/index.html says there should be an "Add" button but I'm not seeing it (screen shot below).  How do I add a text box to a Databricks dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy "Add Markdown" button unfortunately.

The easiest way I've found to do it is to add Markdown text to your notebook and then add that to the dashboard instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In a databricks Dashboard, the text can be added as metadata only. In order to do that create the text using %md in notebook and click on the icon that looks like [icon in the picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XUjg.png) and then select the dashboard that you want to add the text to

Answer (score 0):

The add text button appears if you are creating a SQL Dashboard.  I don't know if Databricks supports it within a notebook.